# Error "application-defined or object-defined"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form contains two subforms (BuyList_Q subform) and (ProductStore_Q subform)
I use a button to transfer data from ProductStore to BuyList

```
Private Sub Command69_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_AddtoOrder_Click

Me.BuyList_Q_subform.Form.BL_PCode.Value = Me.ProductStore_Q_subform.Form.BuyCode.Value
Me.BuyList_Q_subform.Form.BL_PName.Value = Me.ProductStore_Q_subform.Form.P_Name.Value
Me.BuyList_Q_subform.Form.BL_PPrice.Value = Me.ProductStore_Q_subform.Form.P_Price(S).Value
Me.BuyList_Q_subform.Form.BL_PCount.Value = Me.CountNum_txt.Value


Exit_AddtoOrder_Click:
   Exit Sub
Err_AddtoOrder_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_AddtoOrder_Click
End Sub
```

all of this working good but this line

```
Me.BuyList_Q_subform.Form.BL_PPrice.Value = Me.ProductStore_Q_subform.Form.P_Price(S).Value
```

get the error in the title !!
Could you help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with ( ) characters in object name. Advise not to use space nor punctuation/special characters (underscore is exception) in naming convention. If you do, then must enclose in [ ] characters to define name.

Also, not necessary to use `.Value` because this is default property for data input controls.

`Me.BuyList_Q_subform.Form.BL_PPrice = Me.ProductStore_Q_subform.Form.[P_Price(S)]`

Don't do this naming and preserve your sanity.

Comment: thanks, june7. It's working

and thanks for your advance